# Reading all spring beans from a particular context file

Tags: spring

I have a spring context file with several beans of type  defined.
If the input to my program is "help" then I would like to display the bean names from the context file, so that the user can pick a particular bean and give it as input. The program would instantiate the bean with that name and perform some logic.
I am not able to query the list of bean names from a particular context file.
I don't want to use a properties file to store the bean names as I am already using spring context files. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Basically I want the list of beans only defined in a particular context file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring's BeanFactory has got a method called `String[] getBeanDefinitionNames()`. See [Javadoc here.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinitionNames%28%29) You can iterate through the returned list and show them to the user. then you can do a getBean call on the chosen bean name to run the logic.

Comment: I considered this option. But getBeanDefinitionNames() would return back a whole bunch of beans not related. Basically I want the list of beans only defined in a particular context file.

Comment: then create a separate context for each config file or manage it in props...i doesn't see any other option.

Comment: Yes.. There doesnt seem any other option.